# instance method not found (email form)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, email, appdelegate

I'm trying to display an email form appdelegate.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate>

-(void)email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
...
-(void)email {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mail setSubject:@"Ear Dictation issue"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@musicrem.com"];
        [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        NSString *emailBody = @"";
        [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];//this line



    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                        message:@"E-mail is not supported on your device"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"mail failed");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES //this line
                             completion:nil];
}
...
```

And I'm getting this errors on marked lines.

*Instance method '-presentViewController:animated:completion:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')*

and

*Instance method '-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')*

anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are methods from `UIViewController`. They can only be called on instances of `UIViewController`. You are calling them on you app delegate with is not a view controller.

The solution for dismissing is simple:

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

THe solution for presenting the mail controller is to replace `self` with a reference to the proper view controller. One possibility is:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Whether this works or not depends on your view controller structure at the time you try to display the mail controller.

Comment: This should work. Anyway, is there any way I can display it currently shown view controller as I'm using tab bar controller?

Comment: The solution for '-presentViewController:animated:completion:' error is OK but the second one didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you mean the one for `dismiss...` didn't work? It should. What problem do you get when you change `self` to `controller`?

Comment: same, but instead of '-dismiss...' there is '+dismiss...'

Comment: There is no class method that starts with `dismiss...`. Update your question with your changes and the new error. Add this info after all the other current info you posted.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad! It's working as you have written above. Thank you!